# Subfolder .htaccess not found

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi friends i am getting this error anyona cen tell me how can i fix this error. The htaccess my htaccess file is this:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^friends/([\w-]+)/?$ /friends.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^followers/([\w-]+)/?$ /followers.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^settings/([\w-]+)/?$ /settings.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^messages/([\w-]+)/?$ chat.php?message_username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^following/([\w-]+)/?$ following.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^following/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ following.php?username=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^followers/([\w-]+)/?$ followers.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^followers/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ followers.php?username=$1&tpage=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photos/([\w-]+)/?$ userphotos.php?username=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Not Found**

The requested URL /profile/following/demo was not found on this server.

*Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at prototype.kofendurance.com Port 80*

Also i am getting same error all htaccess RewriteRule.

Comment: you should uncomment the first line, at least `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase /`  (just remove the # at the beginning of the line)

Comment: @devsymediane and then i am getting this error: `Not Found

The requested URL /following.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: Your last rule is kicking in and redirecting to `/profile.php?username=profile/following/demo`

Comment: are your files (like following.php) in a subfolder ? If that is the case you should adapt the RewriteBase (like `RewriteBase  /myfolder`)

Comment: @devsymediane Thanks for your answer but it is not working correctly because i haev no following folder. This is .htaccess settings. So also if it was worked then what can i do for other RewriteRule ?

Comment: you said you try to access  /profile/following/demo but there is no "profile" in your htaccess, you should try with `RewriteBase /profile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1st rule to skip files or directories is not right and you need to uncomment opening lines:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /profile/

# skip real files and directories from all the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rest of the rules
```

Comment: thanks for your answer can you tell me what you mean `# skip real files and directories from all the rules`

Comment: this is same error here Not Found

The requested URL /profile.php was not found on this server. So this error when i clicked for user profile. Other RewriteRule also the same error.

Comment: the .htaccess file is in www/profile/(here) the full  url borwser is : `http://prototype.kofendurance.com/profile/demo`

Comment: Thank you so so so much for your best help. You are the best on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Dear the settings.php is not working with .htaccess only that page give me 404 page not found. `http://prototype.kofendurance.com/profile/settings/demo`

Comment: Do you mean i need to use like this ? `RewriteRule ^settings/([\w-]+)/?$ settings.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]` i testted it and again same problem  = `Not Found

The requested URL /settings.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: Dear can i ask you a little question for .htaccess . If you say yes please come chat room. I am waiting you in chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82826/discussion-between-innovation-and-anubhava).

Comment: Dear can i ask you a little question ?

Comment: Sure you can or if it is substantial then feel free to create a new question.

Comment: this is a little question for you i think. How can i enable to see my js files using .htacess ? Like for example if user write `http://www.webname.com/js/filenam.js` then they can see my all js function  but i don't want to show my `js` files also `uploads/name.jpg`'s . How can I prevent it ?

Comment: Above suggested rule won't affect any js/css/image files. There is no way you can hide your css/js/image files from visitors as these are needed by your own pages.